Existence of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\{ f \leq a\}|, |\{ f \geq a\}| \geq \frac{1}{2} |B_{R}(0)|$
I am not able to show the following, geometrically clear claim:
Let $0 < R < R'$ and let $f \in C^\infty(B_{R'}(0))$. Then there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
|\{ f \leq a\}|, |\{ f \geq a\}| \geq \frac{1}{2} |B_{R}(0)|
$$
My Idea would be setting
$$
a = \inf\{b \in \mathbb{R} : |\{ f \leq b\}|\geq \frac{1}{2}|B_{R}(0)| \}.
$$
By continuity of the measure from above, $|\{ f \leq a\}| \geq \frac{1}{2} |B_{R}(0)|$. Assuming $|\{ f \geq a\}| < \frac{1}{2} |B_{R}(0)|$ should lead to a contradiction. Unfortunately I don't know how to finish.
(Note: Not an exercise)

I am using the notation for the Lebesgue measure and $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not using any specific properties of those.
It seems possible to take your $a$ and then as you said show that $A:=|\{f \geq a\}| \geq \frac{1}{2}|B_R(0)|$. If not then $A < \frac{1}{2}|B_R(0)|$ and then by the definition of the inf for all $\epsilon > 0$
$$
\text{|the whole space|} = 2R'  \leq |\{f \leq a\}| + |\{f \geq a\}|< R + \epsilon + R \to 2R = \text{|the smaller ball|}
$$
We have a contradiction because $R < R'$. I guess it should also work for all measurable functions.
